# How do I filter the custom search scope to a specific workspace in Xcode (8)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently working in a workspace, and in that workspace I have multiple project files inside of it. In each of those projects I have localized files that I have already successfully filtered out when using the Find navigator by creating a custom search scope.

But I cannot figure out how to add a filter in the custom search scope to only find results in a certain project. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

In the `Find Navigator` pane, find the folder you want to set the scope to, right-click it, and select 'Create scope from selection'.

[image]

Then, edit the custom search scope by selecting the title, clicking edit, and setting your edit params.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `Show the finder navigator` navigator panel you can select needed search scope, for example:

[image]

Comment: That works to some degree, but it will then show all of my .string files which I also want to ignore. I need some way to edit my custom scope to exclude .string files, and include only a certain project.

Also trying to add a screen shot for visual purposes, but having a hard time doing it. Still new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use bottom text field to top names of needed files for search